# Mapping that proves $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: functions

I think I may have caught a mistake in my professor's lecture notes, and just want to be sure I'm not mistaken.

We want to construct $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, and we consider the mapping
$$f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}, \; n \mapsto \frac{n}{1}.$$
He writes that because $f$ is surjective, $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

However, it is surely not surjective because there are surely rational numbers whose  (unique) simplest form is $\frac{a}{b}$ for $b \neq 1$. The function is injective, surely, because the simplest representative in $\mathbb{Q}$ is unique, but that alone would not imply that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

I think he meant to say that because $f$ is well-defined over the entirety of $\mathbb{Z}$, meaning we actually can identify each integer with a single rational number via the above inclusion, $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

Am I correct or glossing over something?

Answer (score 3):

The correct message is that $f$ is **injective** and therefore we may **view** $\Bbb Z$ as a subset of $\Bbb Q$ (by identifying $\Bbb Z$ with its image under $f$).

In order to *really* have $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Q$, one might call the set constructed $\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}$ and ultimately define
$$\Bbb Q:=(\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}\setminus f[\Bbb Z])\cup\Bbb Z $$
and the make awfully cumbersome definitions for addition etc., e.g.
$$\alpha+_{\Bbb Q}\beta:=\begin{cases}\alpha+\beta&\text{if }\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb Z\\
\frac{a+\beta b}b&\text{if }\alpha=\frac ab\in\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}, b\nmid a, \beta\in \Bbb Z\\
\frac{ad+bc}{bd}&\text{if }\alpha=\frac ab\in\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}, \beta=\frac cd\in\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}, bd\nmid ad+bc\\
f^{-1}(\frac{ad+bc}{bd})&\text{if }\alpha=\frac ab\in\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}, \beta=\frac cd\in\Bbb Q_{\text{temp}}, bd\mid ad+bc\\
\vdots
\end{cases} $$
 Only by identifying the integer $n$ with the rational number (= equivalence class of certain pairs of integers) $\frac n1$, the various rules become adequately simple and straightforward.

Comment: You might often see $f$ being called "the canonical inclusion" when this is the intended interpretation.

Comment: For some reason this isn't clicking for me. If $f$ is injective, $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$. So each rational number is mapped to by at most one distinct integer. Though this makes sense, I don't understand why it's necessary in this case. Even if the function were injective, wouldn't we still be able to conclude that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, provided that $f$ sends every integer to some rational? I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: For the purposes of actually talking about the integers, I completely understand why $f$ is injective (and should be injective for it to make any sense at all), but it doesn't seem immediately necessary to me if we're just proving containment.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, under the normal construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ as the field of fractions for $\mathbb{Z}$, we do not in fact have $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are integers, while the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalence classes of pairs of integers.

However, we do have an injective map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ that arises naturally, and we use this injective map to canonically embed $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$. Using this canonical embedding, we can consider $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ by identifying each of these special elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the corresponding integer.

In other words, there really is no proof of containment here. Just showing that there is a 1-1 correspondence between elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and a special class of elements in $\mathbb{Q}$.